# Using Facebook to login / register - how to still get local user details from my database?

Tags: facebook-login, user-registration

I want my sites users to be able to use facebook to create an account and login

I will gather additional details from the user once they have logged in (id, name, link, etc.) and create a local application database entry for the user.

For future logins, how would i handle the fact that their local db record will now exist?

How do I use the facebook login to return and be able to get the local db user details?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/user_registration/flows/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, authenticating through other providers (openAuth is a biggy too and more generic) is getting quick common.

Here is the facebook info on how to do it with them:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: thanks for this will get back as currently on another project